# Tool to produce self-referential programs?

Tags: theory, self-reference

Many results in computability theory (such as [Kleene's second recursion theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem)) ensure that it is possible to construct programs that can operate over their own source code.  For example, in Michael Sipser's "Introduction to the Theory of Computation," he proves a special case of the Recursion Theorem, which states that any program representing a function that accepts two strings and produces a string can be converted into an equivalent program where the second argument is equal to the program's own source code.  Moreover, this process can be done automatically.

The construction that one uses to produce programs with access to their own source code is well-known (most theory of computation books contain it) and is often used to generate quines.  My question is whether someone has written a general-purpose tool that accepts as input a program in some language (perhaps C, for example) that contains some placeholder for the source of the program, then processes the program to produce a new program with access to its own source code.  This would make it possible, for example, to generate quines automatically, or to write programs that can introspect on their syntax trees (possibly enabling reflection in languages that don't already support it).  If not, I was planning on writing my own version of such a tool, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if this has already been done.

**EDIT**: Based on @Henning Makholm's suggestion, I decided to just sit down and implement such a program.  The resulting program (which I've dubbed "`kleene`") accepts as input a C++ program and produces a new C++ program that can access its own source code by calling the function `kleene::MySource()`.  This means that you could transform this very simple program into a Quine using the `kleene` program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << kleene::MySource() << std::endl;
}
```

If you're curious to check it out, it's available [here on my website](http://www.keithschwarz.com/kleene/).

Comment: Downvoter - Can you please explain what's wrong with this question?

Comment: To "access its own source code" and do anything really interesting, your program as a practical matter will need a lot of parsing, analysis and transformation machinery.  Reading its own code as a text string will buy you extremely little capability, regardless of how cute it is.

Comment: Cool!  I'm glad you did it.  I think others have done it as well.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of examples at the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29) and links therefrom. After looking at one or two it should be obvious how to build a quine generator a given language that takes an arbitrary piece of payload code as input.

One problem with your reflection idea is that the program cannot, in general, *know* that what it has constructed is its own source code.

Comment: That's true, and I am aware of the general construction that you use to do this.  However, my question was mostly whether someone had already done this or whether I should try building it myself.

Comment: It's not clear to me that it would be worth the trouble of publishing (typing out HTML, blog posts and so forth) to share such a geneator explicitly. Once you have one example quine to use as a template, you're in general about eight lines of perl and a here-document away from having a generator anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) is a [program transformation system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation), that will accept programs in arbitrary syntax (described to DMS in an explicit parameter called a "domain description"), parse them to ASTs, carry out analyses and transformations of the ASTs, and can regenerate revised program text from the modified version.

DMS is of course coded in a language (actually as set of domain-specific languages) for which there are already DMS-domain descriptions.  So, DMS can read *itself*, and we use that capability to bootstrap additional DMS capabilities and optimize its performance.
So while we aren't producing quines, we are building programs with self-enhancing code.

And yes, your observation about such a tool providing reflection for arbitrary langauges is smack on.  Most reflection facilities provided in languages allow only access to those things the language-compiler folks thought of paramount importance to access at runtime, such as "method names".  Things *they* weren't interested in, of course, aren't accessible; ever seen a reflection mechanism that will tell you what's in an expression?  In a comment?

DMS provides complete access to *all* the details of the source code, by virtue of inspecting the code from outside, using general purpose, complete mechanisms.  If your language doesn't have reflection, DMS is the way to access the code and reason arbitrarily about it.  Even if your langauge has reflection, DMS can reason about programs in your language in ways that your language cannot, because it can't get access to its own detailed structure.

Comment: Downvoter: It would be nice to explain why you downvoted, rather than flagging this and running.  It answers OP questions directly.